# When using PowerShell 'Invoke-WebRequest' with SSL, how can the 'session' be deleted on the client side after disconnect?

Tags: powershell, ssl

Good morning,

I am using PowerShell to interact with the VMWare vCloud API and am having problems after disconnecting from vCloud.

The process for connecting and using the API is as follows:

- Connect to vCloud using a POST
- Perform necessary operations
- Disconnect using DELETE (This clears down the session at the remote endpoint)

All communication is over HTTPS.

The problem is that when this process run for the first in a new PowerShell console everything is OK.  However if I want to repeat this process again I invariably get the following message:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred     on a send.                            
At C:\tfs\poshvcloud\solutions\poshvcloud\functions\helpers\_Invoke- vCloudRequest.ps1:95 char:17                             
+     $response = Invoke-WebRequest @splat                                                                                   
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                   
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException 
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I have used Fiddler in an attempt to find out what is going on, and interestingly I only ever see 'CONNECT' operations and no attempt to even communicate with vCloud when the above error is displayed.

Indeed I have checked the ServiceEndPoint using `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::FindServicePoint("https://vcloud.example.com/")` and I get an object back and it states I do not have any connections, but for some reason the connection is not re-established when I try to connect again.  It is as if PowerShell does not bother with SSL handshake again.

```
BindIPEndPointDelegate :                                                              
ConnectionLeaseTimeout : -1                                                           
Address                : https://vcloud.example.com/                
MaxIdleTime            : 100000                                                       
UseNagleAlgorithm      : True                                                         
ReceiveBufferSize      : -1                                                           
Expect100Continue      : False                                                        
IdleSince              : 18/07/2014 09:11:34                                          
ProtocolVersion        : 1.1                                                          
ConnectionName         : https                                                        
ConnectionLimit        : 2                                                            
CurrentConnections     : 0                                                            
Certificate            : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate
ClientCertificate      :                                                              
SupportsPipelining     : True
```

One weird thing is that if I attempt to do another operation quickly enough it does go through, but then eventually times out and I get the error.

The only way I can this to work again is to close down my current PowerShell console and start a new one and then load all the necessary modules.

I have tried to 'DisableKeepAlive' on the Inovke-WebRequest but this causes the API calls to fail completely.  I then tried to just do it on the disconnect but this did not work either.

I am thinking that I might need to write my own version Invoke-WebRequest, but I still think I am going to have to clear down things and I not sure how.  I would rather stick with Invoke-WebRequest if I can.

I know that there is PowerCLI from VMWare that takes care of all of this, however that is a huge module and only a fraction of it is applicable to vCloud.  Indeed I started off using it, but due to some inconsistencies and a large dependency I have created my own vCloud module talking to the vCloud REST API directly.

I hope this is enough information, but please let me know if more is required.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kind regards, Russell

Comment: In order to answer your question, we would need to know what is contained in the @splat object being passed to Invoke-WebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = Invoke-WebRequest $adress -Method $Method 
$result.BaseResponse.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the info from [Lavandil's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42227906/11107541) like this:

```
If ($HTTP_Request -eq $null) { } 
Else { $HTTP_Request.BaseResponse.Close() }
```